# При создании нового приложения через django-admin выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

При выполнении django-admin startapp Test из cmd выдаёт ошибку:
django 1.8.6
python 3.5.0
Подскажите плиз - в чём может быть проблема?

```
(vk_spy_site) C:\Windows\system32>django-admin startapp Test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\User\vk_spy_site\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\vk_spy_site\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\user\vk_spy_site\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "c:\users\user\vk_spy_site\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\user\vk_spy_site\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "c:\users\user\vk_spy_site\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'tango_with_django_project'
```

Comment: Выглядет так, как будто у вас 'tango_with_django_project' в списке приложений есть, а физически его нет

Comment: А подскажите пожалуйста - где посмотреть список?

Comment: settings.py INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду settings.py который находится в самом проекте django?

Comment: Да. Я имею ввиду settings.py который находится внутри вашего проекта и содержащий настройки вашего приложения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, не стоит выполнять команду `django-admin startapp Test` в каталоге `C:\Windows\system32`. Во-вторых, если вы скопировали проект "Tango With Django" и переименовали его, то в `settings.py` и в `urls.py` стоит поменять все вхождения `tango_with_django_project` на `vk_spy_site`.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ! 1. Это делалось для примера ошибки 2. Приложение делалось в другом virtualenv(если можно - дайте пожалуйста ссылку на какую-нить доку, ибо мне совсем не очевидно - как приложения из разных virtualenv могут зависеть друг от друга)

Comment: Виртуальные окружения друг от друга полностью независимы. Именно в этом их суть.

Comment: Вероятно я делал всё без virtualenv изначально, а потом уже создал новое, для нового проекта, если я правильно понимаю - нужно "почистить" то, что осталось от предыдущего приложения, но я не очень понимаю где

Comment: создайте новое окружение с ключём –no-site-packages (это значит не тянуть все зависимости от системного) и уже в чистом окружении выполняйте все нужные вам манипуляции. Если что-то пошло не так удаляйте без опасения, и по новой) Один проект - одно окружение.

Comment: Спасибо! Увы, но не удалось